# How can I track banner ad impressions on my website?

Tags: google-analytics

I'd like to be able to create a report that shows how many times a banner on my website was viewed between certain dates. Is there a way to do this through Google Analytics? I looked into DoubleClick for Publishers but it doesn't look like what we need at all.

An example is I have an area at the bottom of my site that holds a banner ad. Some pages have this area, some don't, but most do. When the page loads javascript randomly selects 1 from several banner images to show. I need to know how many times each banner ad is seen by the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could track the occurrence of each banner ad using events. To track events with Google Analytics, you can use the ga function that is included when you embed the Google Analytics script. You need to tell ga you want to send an event and submit a category, action, label, and value. In your case, I'd probably do something like this:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'bannerAd', 'impression', 'nameOfAd', 1);
```

For more details, see the [google docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events).

Comment: Thank you for this. I read another question on StackOverflow that suggested this wasn't an accurate way of doing things and it would cause a lot of slowdown. I immediately haven't tried it myself and just took their word for it. I'm going to give it a shot and see how it goes. I have another question though, I'd only like for an event to to be sent if the banner is scrolled into the viewport (and only once per page load). What's the best way to handle that?

Comment: Create an event handler for the 'scroll' event on the document and send the event once the banner is within the viewport. To prevent the event from being sent twice, you can use a global boolean that you toggle to true once the event has been sent once. It would look something like this:

`var bannerSeen = false;
 document.addEventHandler('scroll', function(event) {
     if (*banner within viewport* && !bannerSeen) {
         ga('send', 'event', 'bannerAd', 'impression', 'nameOfAd', 1);
         bannerSeen = true;
     }
 }`

Comment: You should also remove the event listener once you've sent the event. Scroll event handlers can impact performance.

`var scrollHandler = function(event) {if (bannerInViewport && !bannerSeen) {
   ga(...);
   bannerSeen = false;
   document.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler); }}
document.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler);`

Comment: Thanks! Any chance you could add that to the answer? I seem to be having some trouble replicating it from your comments. I'm getting this: ``Uncaught TypeError: document.addEventHandler is not a function``.

Comment: Sorry! that was a typo. You want document.addEventListener

Comment: Thanks. Still not sure I have this. The script spread out across two comments is a little confusing. Here's a JSFiddler I made. I'm not sure how to remove the event listener like you suggested. http://jsfiddle.net/8so2ueLm/

Comment: you're very close. in order to remove an event listener, you need to have a reference to the function that serves as the event listener. so define the function and assign it to a var like so...https://jsfiddle.net/8so2ueLm/1/

Comment: Thank you for that. I had some trouble wrapping my head around the concept of applying a function to a variable.